# What are the equivalents of millionnaire, multimillionaire and billionaire in Japanese?

Tags: word-requests, culture

I'm talking about the "cultural" ones, because with the yen currency the scale is completely different (millionnaire with yen is only about having approximately 10 000 usd so I don't think it's the real equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[億万長者【おくまんちょうじゃ】](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%84%84%E4%B8%87%E9%95%B7%E8%80%85&ref=sa) is the best-known word. Actually there is also a word [百万長者](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BE%E4%B8%87%E9%95%B7%E8%80%85), but it's not commonly used for the obvious reason.

ミリオネア is at least understood [because of this TV program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz_$_Millionaire), but it's not used in daily conversations.

Comment: 億万長者 is a word that just means " rich person" without referring especially to an amount of money ?

Comment: @Jirei I assume an 億万長者 has at least 100M yen, but basically it vaguely refers to a super-rich person. Bill Gates is still safely an 億万長者, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the word [大富豪]{だい・ふ・ごう}, but I don't know if it's commonly used other than for the [card game](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E5%AF%8C%E8%B1%AA).

Comment: It is definitely used in the 'extremely rich person' meaning.  I don't think it's *terribly* uncommon, though my intuition might not be reliable on that point.  At any rate, I learned in context with that meaning, and you can find plenty of examples in [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/).